# Error llamando a una function personalizada en php me da este error Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, function

Llamo a la function  ContarPuestos() en la linea 49 de ListadoBusquedas20.php

```
<span class="subheading"><?php  echo ContarPuestos( 0) ?></span>
```

Por otro lado en la misma pagina incluyo una lineas antes, una pagina donde tengo la function y otras dos que se llama Funcionador.php

```
 include('Funcionador.php');
```

dentro de funcionador, esta la function

```
function ContarPuestos($fEstado) {//0 No, 1 Publicado 2 Contratado, 3 Baja ..otros  
include("Conexion.php");
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL. FUNCTION TagSoft" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
$BQuery ="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM PuestosJustris where Publicado = ".$fEstado;
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$BQuery);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
return $fila;
}
```

Me arroja el error siguiente en la pagina que llama a la function

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /public_html/phpAux/ListadoBusquedas20.php on line 49
```

Comment: A primera vista tu función retorna un array, y no puedes imprimir un array con `echo`, recomendaría que la función retorne `return $fila['total'];`

Comment: La function `echo` siempre intenta imprimir un string, pero de tu función recibes un array de objetos, debes tratar esto primero en tu función `ContarPuestos` para poder imprimirlo, antes de hacer return has `var_dump($fila);die();` con el objetivo de revisar como retornarás el valor esperado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primera vista tu función  retorna un `array` asociativo como resultado de [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php),  no puedes imprimir un `array` con `echo`.

Si desea imprimir el total  la función debe retornar el valor y no el array.

```
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
return $fila['total'];
```

Comment: GRACIAS ..!!!!!!